# Setting up PayPal Pro in CiviCRM

Tags: payment-processor, paypal

Currently trying to set up PayPal Pro as a Payment Processor in Civi 4.6.7, following the instructions here:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/PayPal+Website+Payments+Pro+and+Express+Configuration

Am I right in thinking that this requires the PayPal Classic API instead of the PayPal REST API? The instructions seem to differ quite a lot from what is presented on PayPal Dev.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully someone else more knowledgeable chimes in, but in short: yes.  The PayPal payment processor uses the older PayPal APIs.  My understanding is that the new APIs are actually the PayFlow APIs, and thus are compatible with the PayFlow processor plugin.  Each time this has come up for me, we were able to get the older API from PayPal, but you need to speak on the phone to a person.

Comment: getting the older paypal APIs is getting harder.  The various options are very complex: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/  Hopefully we get to newer REST API or plugin to address.